# security checks in tor browser in the form of a capture

Tags: security

How to bypass security checks in tor browser because whenever i enter a site in the address bar of tor browser a security check appears in the form of a capture? So how can i bypass security checks in tor browser?

Comment: The only way to bypass this is to not use Tor, or ask the website to stop blocking Tor. Your mileage will vary.